# Dynamic Object Destructuring

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I'm trying to figure out a way to destructure an object based on a dynamic list/array of property names.

Say, I have an object:

```
let individual = {
    id: 1,
    fullname: 'User Name',
    sex: 'M',
    birthdate: new Date(1975, 3, 15)
};
```

and a dynamic array with property names:

```
let properties = ['id', 'fullname','sex'];
```

is there a way to simply get a resulting object with only the properties specified in the array:

```
{
    id: 1,
    fullname: 'User Name',
    sex: 'M'
}
```

Comment: What is the real world context for the ask? is it an app that filters? What are you trying to achieve

Comment: lodash 'pick' works in that way, if usage of the library is appropriate for you. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pick

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if it can be done with destructuring, but it can be done simply with a couple of functions.

```js
let individual = {
  id: 1,
  fullname: 'User Name',
  sex: 'M',
  birthdate: new Date(1975, 3, 15)
};
let properties = ['id', 'fullname','sex'];

let result = Object.fromEntries(properties.map(prop => [prop, individual[prop]]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I like the use of `fromEntries`

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun. Kind of dynamic destructure)

```js
// Set dynamic destructure function
const dd = (x, y, z = {}) => { for(e of y) { ({[e]:z[e]} = x); } return z; };

// Old object
let individual = {
    id: 1,
    fullname: 'User Name',
    sex: 'M',
    birthdate: new Date(1975, 3, 15)
};

// Property names to copy
let properties = ['id', 'fullname','sex'];

// Do dynamic destructure
console.log(dd(individual, properties));
```

Answer (score 2):

"dynamic" with reduce, not limited to three fields.

```
properties.reduce((acc, curr )=> { acc[curr] = individual[curr];
return acc;
 } , {})
```